# (How) can you add methods to a collection of entities in Google App Engine python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, collections, model

In GAE-python, you can model a one-to-many relationship by assigning a reference property to the child model.

```
class Book(db.Model):
   title = db.StringProperty()
class Author(db.Model):
   book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, collection_name = 'authors')
   is_primary = db.BooleanProperty()
   name = db.StringProperty()
```

This way, I can access the `authors` property of a book object instance to get a query-able list of all the Author instances that reference it.

What I want to do is supplement the `authors` property with a method. A trivial example based on the preceding one would be a function that returns just the primary authors sorted in alphabetical. What's the syntax for something like this?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please explain what do you mean by "collection of entities". Do you mean classes? Is this RPC? Mixin?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is one to many realtionship. There is no db.Referencelist property.I guess this will  help you out.

```
class Book(db.Model):
   title = db.StringProperty()
class Author(db.Model):
   is_primary = db.BooleanProperty()
   name = db.StringProperty()

book = Book(title="what is life")
book.put()

author1 = Author(parent=book,is_primary=true,name='author1')
author1.put()

author2 = Author(parent=book,is_primary=true,name='author2')
author2.put()

# from book to authors
book_authors = Author.all().ancestor(book)
```